# Elegant use of SQL LAG() function to return last workingday in previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to create a query in which I have to find the last workingday in the previous month. I know how to do this with my date dimension that has an `IsWorkingday` flag and joining to the date one month ago from today and from there find the max(dateid).

While I was doing this I was thinking shouldn't there be a more elegant solution like using `LAG()` with a specific partition by and order by.

I played with it for a while but couldn't find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Include your current query as well.

Comment: Hi Gordon, the data can be very simple. Just records from a date dimension, one record per day. Normally LAG() gives you the previous record (day) but I thought maybe it can be tweaked to return the last day of previous month.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really what LAG() is for.  It's better suited for things like calculating a running total.  Please google the LAG() function in SQL Server if you want a better understanding.

A possibly more elegant solution would be to get the first working day of the current month, and select the first working day before it.

Without knowing your table structure and data, it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: `LAG()` is not used for calculating running totals.  Period.